# C: Cannot read from a pipe attached to the stdout of a child process

Tags: c

I am attempting a create a front end to a console music player and I have to interact with it by sending it commands to its `stdin` while reading its status back from its `stdout`, so I set up 2 pipes just for that. Sending commands to the child process' `stdin` works, but I cannot read any data from its `stdout` (`read()` always returns -1, `errno` is set to `Resource temporarily unavailable`).

When starting the music player by itself in the terminal with the same arguments, it outputs the following:

```
S05:05
T00:00
T00:01
T00:02
T00:03
T00:04
T00:05
...
```

Every line from that music player is guaranteed to be 6 lines + newline, so the expected output from the parent program should be:

```
S05:05 T00:00 T00:01 T00:02 T00:03 T00:04 T00:05...
```

(newlines do not work when the terminal is set to raw mode)

However, nothing at all is ever read from the child process. Any help as to why this happens and how to solve this would be much appreciated.

Here is the code of the parent program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>

int main() {
    system("/bin/stty raw");            // Set up the terminal so that stdin is non-blocking

    pid_t p;
    int pipe_stdin[2], pipe_stdout[2];

    if(pipe(pipe_stdin)) return -1;     // Initialize child stdin pipe
    if(pipe(pipe_stdout)) return -1;    // Initialize child stdout pipe

    // Make reading from the pipe non-blocking
    fcntl(pipe_stdout[0], F_SETFL, fcntl(pipe_stdout[0], F_GETFL) | O_NONBLOCK);

    if((p = fork()) == 0) {             // Create the child process
        close(pipe_stdin[1]);           // Close unnecessary pipe ends to the child
        close(pipe_stdout[0]);

        dup2(pipe_stdin[0], 0);         // Redirect stdin to a pipe
        dup2(pipe_stdout[1], 1);        // Redirect stdout to a pipe

        // Start the process
        execl("/bin/sh", "sh", "-c", "./openmpt ./spacedeb.mod 2>/dev/null", NULL);
        exit(1);
    }

    close(pipe_stdin[0]);               // Close unnecessary pipe ends to the parent
    close(pipe_stdout[1]);

    int codec_write = pipe_stdin[1], codec_read = pipe_stdout[0], playing = 1;
    char buf[8];

    while(playing) {
        // Read input from the child process (read() always returns -1 here!)
        while(read(codec_read, buf, 7) >= 0) {
            printf("%s ", buf);
        }

        // Send user data to the child process (this part works!)
        switch(getchar()) {
            case ' ': write(codec_write, "P\n", 2); break;  // Play & Pause
            case 13: write(codec_write, "R\n", 2); break;   // Reset
            case 27: playing = 0; break;                    // Exit
        }
    }

    close(codec_write);                 // Close the pipes
    close(codec_read);
    system("killall -9 openmpt");       // Kill the child process

    system("/bin/stty cooked");         // Reset the terminal back to its original state
}
```

And here is the code of the player (if necessary, it should not be a problem though):

```
#include <memory.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <libopenmpt/libopenmpt.h>
#include <libopenmpt/libopenmpt_stream_callbacks_file.h>
#include "portaudio.h"

#define BUFFERSIZE 512
#define SAMPLERATE 48000

static int16_t buffer[BUFFERSIZE * 2];

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    // Initialize OpenMPT and load the module
    FILE *file = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    openmpt_module *mod = openmpt_module_create2(openmpt_stream_get_file_callbacks(), file, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);  
    fclose(file);

    // Output the length of the tune
    printf("T%02d:%02d\n", (int)openmpt_module_get_duration_seconds(mod) / 60, (int)openmpt_module_get_duration_seconds(mod) % 60);

    // Initialize PortAudio
    PaStream *stream;
    Pa_Initialize();
    Pa_OpenDefaultStream(&stream, 0, 2, paInt16, SAMPLERATE, BUFFERSIZE, NULL, NULL);
    Pa_StartStream(stream);
    
    unsigned long i, count = 0, prev = -1, paused = 0;
    char buf[3] = { 0 };

    // Set stdin to non-blocking
    fcntl(0, F_SETFL, fcntl(0, F_GETFL) | O_NONBLOCK);

    while (1) {
        // Read commands from the parent program
        while(read(0, buf, 2) >= 0) {
            switch(buf[0]) {
                case 'P':
                    paused ^= 1;
                    printf("%s--:--\n", paused ? "P" : "R");
                    break;

                case 'R':
                    openmpt_module_set_position_order_row(mod, 0, 0);
                    break;
            }
        }

        // Display the current position of the tune
        if((int)openmpt_module_get_position_seconds(mod) != prev) {
            printf("T%02d:%02d\n", (int)openmpt_module_get_position_seconds(mod) / 60, (int)openmpt_module_get_position_seconds(mod) % 60);
            prev = (int)openmpt_module_get_position_seconds(mod);
        }

        // Play audio, if not paused
        if(!paused) {
            count = openmpt_module_read_interleaved_stereo(mod, SAMPLERATE, BUFFERSIZE, buffer);
        
            if (!count) {
                break;
            }
            
            Pa_WriteStream(stream, buffer, count);
        }
    }
    
    // Tell the parent that we're done
    printf("E--:--\n");

    // Stop PortAudio
    Pa_StopStream(stream);
    Pa_CloseStream(stream);
    Pa_Terminate();
    
    // Stop OpenMPT
    openmpt_module_destroy(mod);
}
```

Comment: I would also appreciate if you also commented the reason why you downvoted this question. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind, I figured it out myself, the player needed `fflush(stdout);` after the `printf` statements. Now everything works as intended.